# Trouble with Merging Sorted Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, merge, array-merge

I am struggling to solve this problem, merging two sorted arrays (or vectors in this specific case). I am getting very weird output when logging the vector elements to the console. My ideal output would be all of the numbers in order.

**Here is the code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> vec1 = {0, 3, 4, 31};
  vector<int> vec2 = {4, 6, 30};

  vector<int>::iterator it1 = vec1.begin();
  auto it2 = vec2.begin();

  bool keep_going = true;

  for ( ; it2 != vec2.end(); it2++) {
    for ( ; it1 != vec1.end() && keep_going; it1++) {
      if (*it1 < *it2) {
        vec1.insert(it1, *it2);
        keep_going = false;
      }
    }
    keep_going = true;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++) {
    cout << vec1[i] << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Here is what the console says:**

```
49
0
4
0
3
4
31
free(): invalid pointer
exited, aborted
```

Comment: There are [std::merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) and [std::inplace_merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge) algorithm functions that do this.

Comment: You can't use nested `for` loops for this. You have to be able to move each iterator independently for each element.

Comment: There's also something called "iterator invalidation rules", do a bit of reading on that term.

Comment: 1. Use a third vector to store the result. 2. Use a different iterator for each vector. 3. You do not need a nested loop.

Comment: *My ideal output would be all of the numbers in order* -- If all that's required is to output the numbers in order, then this becomes, literally, a 3 line C++ program using `std::merge`.

Comment: [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0debd0acb6b6052).  Now, the issue is whether you want to fix your code (which is really badly broken in terms of how to solve the problem), or use `std::merge` and let it do the work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This looks like a homework; `std::merge` is, most likely, not allowed. They are, probably, asked to implement `merge`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a reason for not using `std::merge`, it can be done by hand provided:

- you do not used nested loops
- you reset iterators after each insert (the insert invalides the operator)

The merge operation could be coded as:

```
  while(it2 != vec2.end()) {                             // loop while smth to insert
    while((it1 != vec1.end()) && (*it1 <= *it2)) it1++;  // search in vec1 where to insert
    int i = it1 - vec1.begin();                          // store the position
    vec1.insert(it1, *it2++);                            // insert the value
    it1 = vec1.begin() + i + 1;                          // and restore the iterator
  }
```